# Review Questions before Graph Theory

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer, $n ≥ 2$, and let $D = \{1,\ldots,n−1\}$. Consider the function $f:D \to\mathbb Z$ where
>   $$f(k) = k(n − k).$$
>   Define
>   $$\ell = \min_{k\in D}f(k),$$
>   $$L = \{k\in D : f(k) = \ell\},$$
>   $$u=\max_{k\in D}f(k), $$
>   $$U =\{k∈D:f(k)=u\}.$$
>   Determine (with proof) $\ell, L, u,$ and $U$.

---

This was one of the review questions on an unmarked assignment so we didn't get any answers. I'm really curious how this question is done and can't quite remember how to do it.

And help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k(n-k) = n^2/4-(k-n/2)^2$ by completing the square. This function is maximised if the bracket is zero.

- If $n$ is even, there is a $k$ so that the bracket is zero ($k=n/2$), so the maximum is $n^2/4$ when $k=n/2$.
- If $n$ is odd, there are two values that give the maximum: those that minimise the bracket, which are those on either side of $n/2$, i.e. $(n \pm 1)/2$, and the maximum is then $(n^2-1)/4$.

The minimum and minimisers can be found in the same way by considering when $(k-n/2)^2$ is maximised (hint: look at the ends).